# How does Power Mosfet works?

Tags: mosfet

I am using an IC [IPS521](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/ips521.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c3c24d161d) which is a power MOSFET. I would like to study the working principle of this 5 Pin MOSFET.

It's described as a "Fully protected High Side power MOSFET Switch".

[image]

Comment: They put magic smoke in the mosfet at the factory. If your design is good, it will work like it says in the datasheet. If your design is bad, or a fault occurs, then the magic smoke may leak out, and the mosfet will not work anymore.

Comment: If you want to know something specific, please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: Read spec. until you understand what a "smart" High Side Switch does. Which part do you not understand?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Have you read the "be nice policy"?

Comment: right, it could be interpretted in the perjorative sense or in his language as a direct question.

Answer (score 2):

Although the IPS500 series is being phased out (not recommended for new design ) and replaced with IPS600 series, a good way to learn is to include keywords in your search like "application note".

Read here https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/an-1117.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153559670ed1073

Smart Automotive switches for High or Low Side switching demand, that they survive Load dump from A/C clutch, x2 Vbat up to 70V spikes and -Vbat for those that jump start vehicles with cables from trucks. They also have many other std. fault protection and detection features.

Comment: Nice touch with Application Note

Answer (score 0):

From the datasheet.

Features

• Over temperature protection (with auto-restart)

• Short-circuit protection (current limit)

• Active clamp

• E.S.D protection

• Status feedback

• Open load detection

• Logic ground isolated from power ground

So the its a MOSFET with added protection circuitry.